# Using differentiability to prove linearity

Tags: analysis

Let $f: U \subset \mathbb{R}^{m} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be differentiable in $U$ (open set), let $a \in U$ such that $[a,a+h] \in U$ and $|f'(x) - T| \leq M$ $\forall x \in (a,a+h)$ we know that $|f(a+h) - f(a) - T(v)| \leq M |v|$.

Show that $g_{a}(v) = f(a+v) - f(a)$ is a linear function.

I was trying to use the definition $g_{a}(v+u) =g_{a}(v) + g_{a}(u)$ but there to no avail.

Comment: what is T exactly?

Comment: $T$ is a ordinary linear transformation